# Cannot access SOAP service when Flex 3 app is compiled

Tags: apache-flex

I've got a flex app that hits a remote SOAP service and populates a list with the results.

It works fine when i run it through flex builder, but when i compile the application and move it onto a webserver it can't access the services.

I've tried it from a standalone webserver and on my own machine. I'm assuming that there's a security issue that i've missed as i can't think of any other reason why it's ok in flex builder but not when compiled on the same box.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a crossdomain.xml issue?

The web server running the SOAP service needs crossdomain.xml file to allow your flash movie to access it. See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

Comment: I believe it is, i was told by the vendor that there was a crossdomain file but i've just actually checked there isn't.

Thanks!